# Dissecting/unpacking sniffed packages for analytics (packet-loss, signal strenght, retransmission..) using Raspberry pi kali linux

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, packet-sniffers, sniffing, packet-loss

I am quite new to **sniffing/hacking** and trying to do a nice script for **parsing/sorting packages**. I would like to `store` and `sort` **TCP-packages flags**(*retransmission*, *double ack*, *lost segment*..) for each packet. I would also like to see the **signal strength of the AP** and the **payload for each packet**.

The code is will be used to sniff packages between a specific client and a server with static addresses and specified port. I using a Raspberry Pi with kali linux and the sniffing-session must be done in monitor mode.

When completed the script should be able to store packages that have been lost between the client and server.

I have messed around with aircrack-ng(airodump..), wireshark, scapy, sockets and wifite to evaluate be behavior of packages transmitted. 
But nothing gave the output i prefered.

Is there a way do dissect each packages into variables to easily use in a script? 
Is there a way to evaluate TCP-flags? and to count them?

I have tried to do a sniffing-session with multiple approaches and store it in a pcap-file and later analyze the session in wireshark.

A preferred output is in columns:

```
Packet number | source.ip -> destination.ip | signal strenght | payload
```

And after each session there should be a summarizing of the TCP-packages Retransmittet, lost segment, double ack. Like:

```
packages count:  Retransmitted: X | lost_segment: X | double ack:
```

Comment: Wireshark isn't easily scriptable. Also, "Packet number" only exist in wireshark, they are not real. You're saying that you tried EVERYTHING from raw sockets to Scapy without any success ?, I would doubt that. What have you tried on those tools ?

Comment: yeah im trying to learn about the sniffing and internet protocols. I have tried to research how to handle packages with scapy and unpack/dissect every layer but couldn't find any concrete example.. Ive tried to merge different scripts to and adjust them to give me correct output. On Raspberry Pi the sockets is inconsistent when using monitor mode, sometimes it displays nothing and sometimes it works.. Do your have good threads or tutorials about getting through the layers using scapy or some other library? Sorry for the dramatic "everything" hehe